# How to get multiple values from ASP.NET Listbox

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I have the following listbox on aspx page.

```
  <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="lbA" Visible="true" 
                SelectionMode="Multiple" DataTextField="A_FACTOR" 
                DataValueField="A_ID" Width="218px"> </asp:ListBox>
```

then on code behind I have the following on a button click I have the following.

```
string aFactor = "";

 foreach(ListItem listItem in lbA.Items)
    {
        if (listItem.Selected)
        {
            aFactor += listItem.Value + ",";
        }
    }
```

when I select values (any values) from the listbox, the listItem.Selected is always
false and I am not able to get values because of that. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: how are you initialiszing lbA ?

Comment: Adel - lbA is a listbox control that is bound to database. does it make sense? or am I missing something. thank you.

Comment: You are probably intializing lbA incorrectly, because your code is correct

Comment: Is the listbox being emptied before that code runs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting all selected values from an ASP ListBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586078/getting-all-selected-values-from-an-asp-listbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I thought, you were doing something wrong outside the code you have provided, please see the answer of this link :

[Selected item in list box is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859885/selected-item-in-list-box-is-null)

Comment: I had outside !Page.IsPostBack. :(  I was over confident with my code. I learnt my lesson.

Answer (score 0):

populate the list in

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
}
```

at the time of form load