# ASP.NET Assigning Roles to Users - 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object. '

Tags: object, exception, instance, roles

I am creating a basic role manager system where users of my website can be added to specific roles so that they can access exclusive parts of the website.

I have managed to add roles to my database but when I try to assign users to a particular role I get the 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error and I can't work out why.

Here is my code:

```
protected void btnAssignRole_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(lstRoles.SelectedItem.Value))
            {
                Roles.AddUserToRole(lstUsers.SelectedItem.Value, lstRoles.SelectedItem.Value);
                lstRoles.DataBind();
                lstUsers.DataBind();
                litRoleResult.Text = "User added to Role";
            }
            else
            {
                litRoleResult.Text = "User already in this Role";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            litRoleResult.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<h1>Admin Page Test</h1>
<a href="ProductsAdmin.aspx">Products Admin</a>

<div id="UserAdmin">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRoleName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnAddRole" runat="server" Text="Create Role" OnClick="btnAddRole_Click" />
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Available Roles"></asp:Label>
        <asp:ListBox ID="lstRoles" runat="server" DataSourceID="Roles_DS" DataTextField="RoleName" DataValueField="RoleName"></asp:ListBox>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Roles_DS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:db_1318766_zaraConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [RoleName] FROM [vw_aspnet_Roles]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:Literal ID="litRole" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Available Users"></asp:Label>
        <asp:ListBox ID="lstUsers" runat="server" DataSourceID="Users_DS" DataTextField="UserName" DataValueField="UserName">
        </asp:ListBox>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Users_DS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:db_1318766_zaraConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [UserName] FROM [vw_aspnet_Users]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnAssignRole" runat="server" Text="Assign Role to User" OnClick="btnAssignRole_Click" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Remove User from Role" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Delete Role(s)" />
    </div>
    <asp:Literal ID="litRoleResult" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</div>
```

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a few objects that must be declared on a Global scale: Roles, lstRoles, lstUsers and litRoleResult all must be initialized at some point because they're not initialized in your method.
My suspicion is that if you set a breakpoint on this method, one of those objects will be null.  Also, if `lstUsers or lstRoles` doesn't have an item selected, I'm pretty sure that calling `SelectedItem.Value` will throw an exception; ensure that `SelectedItem` has a value (does it have a .HasValue property?) before you call the value.

EDIT: Sorry, I missed the ASP.NET portion; I'm assuming that your lstUsers and lstRoles are objects on your page.  In that case, I'm definitely leaning towards the `SelectedItem` property being `null`.  Does the list allow multi-select?

Comment: Hi. Roles is the 'Roles' class within System.Web.Security. I should have added that I have declared this namespace at the top of the .cs file. lstRoles and lstUsers are listbox controls which are bound to my database and litRoleResult is a literal control. I'll amend my original post with the html as well.

Comment: Just found this on another question; seems there's some issue with DataBind() that causes the `.SelectedValue` to come back as null.  
See if this helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859885/selected-item-in-list-box-is-null

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED

Using the link in Kalmino's comment I amended the following:

In the Page_Load method I changed

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            lstRoles.DataBind();
            lstUsers.DataBind();

        }
    }
```

to

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            lstRoles.DataBind();
            lstUsers.DataBind();

        }
    }
```

From my original question I also changed the

```
if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(lstRoles.SelectedItem.Value))
```

line to

```
if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(lstUsers.SelectedItem.Text, lstRoles.SelectedItem.Text))
```